# Power BI - Duplicate label for Shape Map

Tags: powerbi, label, powerbi-desktop, mousehover

So I have created a map using the shape map visualization linking my JSON with my datasheet from excel. My issue is that when I need to link the color to the maps I have to add the column from the excelsheet to "Legend" and "Color Saturation" to show the values that I would like to be represented by the color scheme available.

After this is done, when the mouse hovers over the polygons in the shape map the "Legend" and "Color Saturation" are shown as a label for the shape map of which is an issue because they both have the same indicator used. How do I switch off one or both so it doesnt show a duplicate in my hover over label? [Label are based off of selected Legend and Color Saturation[Hover over label on map is showing a duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ykKb.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jhrsl.jpg)

I have tried to not add the phase to color saturation and legend but if I do that the symbology for the shape map will not be the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was hoping the image I attached would give some detail. As you will see there is a duplicate in the hover over label for each polygon. I am trying to figure out how to remove the duplicate label when the mouse hovers over these polygons.